# ANGULAR - ngFor creating cards out of order when consuming Pokeapi api

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor

I'm finishing my pokedex and one of the things that's been bothering me is the fact that the cards that angular creates with ngFor are coming out of order. I'm just starting to use Angular and I wanted some help with this.

demo - https://pokedex-jrsbaum.vercel.app

HTML

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 ml-2 mt-2"
    *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemons" >
     <div class="card-container">
       <div class="card">
         <div
           class="front"
           [ngStyle]="{
             'background-color': getColors(pokemon.types[0]?.type.name)
           }"
         >
```

TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PokemonService } from 'src/app/services/pokemon.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pokemon-list',
  templateUrl: './pokemon-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pokemon-list.component.css'],
})
export class PokemonListComponent implements OnInit {
  pokemons: any[] = [];
  species: any[] = [];

  constructor(public pokemonService: PokemonService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pokemonService.getPokemons().subscribe((response: any) => {
      response.results.forEach((result: { name: string }) => {
        this.pokemonService
          .getDetails(result.name)
          .subscribe((uniqResponse: any) => {
            this.pokemons.push(uniqResponse);
          });
        this.pokemonService
          .getSpecies(result.name)
          .subscribe((uniqResponse: any) => {
            this.species.push(uniqResponse);
          });
      });
    });
  }
```

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PokemonService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  //Get Pokemons
  getPokemons() {
    return this.http.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151`);
  }

  //Get More Pokemon Data
  getDetails(name: string) {
    return this.http.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`);
  }

  getSpecies(name: string) {
    return this.http.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${name}/`);
  }
}
```

What I think is happening is that ngFor is making the call and stacking the cards, and the ones that are ready it releases before.

Comment: I've used angular for a while, and never got ngFor unordered. the for loop is synchronized, but the subscription is unsynchronized, have you tried debugging what's inside the subscription? or console logging this.pokemons?

Comment: in short, the calls might be in order, but the responses may not be. if you really want your cards to be in order, you need away to sort it.

Comment: and how do you think i could do that?

Comment: You want to order them by name?

Answer (score 2):

`*ngFor` orders array elements based on array indices. In your code, values pushed into `pokemons` array are fetched from some service call, which returns results asynchronously. This explains the random ordering.

To solve this, one solution is to use the array indices when inserting values into `pokemons` array.

Replace

```
this.pokemons.push(uniqResponse);
```

with

```
const index = uniqResponse.id - 1;
this.pokemons[index] = uniqResponse;
```

Check out my [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gufsv3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fpokemon-list%2Fpokemon-list.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fpokemon-list%2Fpokemon-list.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). You can see the pokemon Ids displayed in order.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but it didn't work. I edited the post and put the service part.

Comment: @JúniorBaum - I forgot to decrement index by 1 since arrays start with zero. See my updated answer and the linked StackBlitz demo.

Comment: hey man, thank you very much. This solved my problem! I'm still learning web development. Thanks!

Comment: @JúniorBaum - You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer by ticking the checkmark. Good luck on your learning journey.